# Would it be more accurate to say $2 \ge V - E + F \ge \text{Euler characteristic}$ for $V \ge 2$?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I only have a strong understanding of highschool level math right now, so apologies if this question has an obvious answer, but, shouldn't the formula be $2 \ge V - E + F \ge \text{Euler characteristic}$ for $V \ge 2$?

For example, if I'm on a torus, sure, I can increase the edges without increasing the faces twice, therefore making $V - E + F = 0$ for any graph that builds upon that graph.

But what if I chose to just zoom in a bit and make sure my graph never creates a loop around a circle (for example, drawing on a coffee mug without touching the handle or ever looping around the cup)? Then wouldn't $V - E + F = 2$? or, if I only make a loop around one circle but not another, then wouldn't $V - E + F = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even more accurate would be to say that $V-E+F$ is equal to the Euler characteristic for any **cellular embedding** of a graph in a surface. A cellular embedding is one in which every face is homeomorphic to an open disk.

In the example where you "zoom in a bit" and draw a graph on the torus in the same way you'd draw it on the plane, the "outside face" will not be homeomorphic to an open disk: it will be homeomorphic to a punctured torus. (The word "outside face" is not precise on the torus, but it's hopefully clear what I mean.) If there is a loop only around one circle, then the "outside face" will be homeomorphic to an open cylinder - again, not the same thing as a disk.

Any cellular embedding on the torus will have $V-E+F=0$; intuitively, at some point we must draw two "extra" edges that cut an existing face into shape rather than divide it into two faces. This generalizes to other surfaces.

Otherwise, if the embedding is not a cellular embedding, then yes - we only get a range within which $V-E+F$ can fall.

Comment: it's gonna take me a minute to fully understand/parse this answer, however, would it be a fair approximation to say that some graph that's on a torus but doesn't wrap around either circle isn't really "on a torus" because the graph itself can be mapped onto a flat surface without loss of generality?

Comment: Essentially, yes. But "doesn't wrap around either circle" is too vague to be used in proving theorems, and so the way we formalize that idea is by looking at the topology of the faces - checking if the embedding is a cellular embedding.

Comment: makes sense, thank you!

Comment: after more consideration I think I understand your answer - once every face "looks flat" (is homeomorphic to a disk) then the original V-E+F argument for a flat plane holds, therefore V-E+F is constant, otherwise certain connections might change V-E+F

Comment: This also seems to suggest that V-E+F can't be more than 2 unless your initial surface contains more than 1 face, since you can always start out with V-E+F = 2 (given 1 initial face), and can only ever change a surface by "cutting" it, which reduces V-E+F. is this true? it would seem pretty odd if you could add faces just by adding vertices and edges

Comment: taking this train of thought further, what happens when you "smush" two surfaces together? it would seem to me their differences from 2 would get added together, right? (where En is Euler characteristic of surface n: $2 + (E1 - 2) + (E2 -2)$). Because if I can "cut" one surface and still have 1 face then that one face should still be connected to the "other" surface, and shouldn't effect that other surface, so I should be able to make each of the possible cuts for each surface without changing the number of faces. Please let me know if I'm completely off-base here

Comment: The faces where they're smushed together will become a single face with two boundaries - no longer a disk.